# what happens when typeid(obj) is compiled - C++

Tags: c++, clang++, rtti, libc++

I have a sample class in my program like below

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplate1
{
public:
    T a;

    MyTemplate1(T other){
        a = other;
    }
};
```

In my main program, if I just create object of type `MyTemplate1<int>`, it is not showing any typeinfo objects in readelf output. But if I add some code like below

```
MyTemplate1<int> obj = 12;
if(typeid(obj) == typeid(MyTemplate1<float>))
   //some code
```

readelf output is showing typeinfo for `MyTemplate1<int>` and typeinfo for `MyTemplate1<float>`.

```
$readelf -s -W <objfile> | findstr -I "MyTemplate"
9023: 00000000     8 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT 2899 _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
9024: 00000000     8 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT 2894 _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
```

Could somebody please explain what these OBJECTs correspond to? Are these global instances of std::type_info for the class MyTemplate1? What exactly is happening under the hood?

Comment: Templates need to be instatiated at compile time to become significant for `typeid()` generated code. If `if I just create object of type MyTemplate1<int>` isn't used any further, the compiler might likely optimize it away.

Comment: The standard requires objects produced by `typeid` to have static storage duration.  The objects you are seeing are presumably objects of type `std::type_info` with static storage duration that your compiler generates to represent results of the `typeid` constructs.    The names are mangled using a scheme that is specific to your compiler.   `MyTemplate1<int>` and `MyTemplate1<float>` are distinct types (different instantiations of a template) so their type information will be stored in different objects.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to construct any objects instantiating `MyTemplate1<T>`
in a compilation unit to see typeinfo objects describing instantiation classes
of that template in the global symbol table of the object file. You need only
to refer to the `typeid` of such a class:-

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T>
class MyTemplate1
{
public:
    T a;

    MyTemplate1(T other){
        a = other;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    return (typeid(MyTemplate1<int>) == typeid(MyTemplate1<float>));
}

$ clang++ -Wall -c main.cpp
$ readelf -s -W main.o | grep MyTemplate1
     5: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   15 _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
     6: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   10 _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
     7: 0000000000000000    17 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   13 _ZTS11MyTemplate1IfE
     8: 0000000000000000    17 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT    8 _ZTS11MyTemplate1IiE

$ c++filt _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
typeinfo for MyTemplate1<float>
$ c++filt _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
typeinfo for MyTemplate1<int>
$ c++filt _ZTS11MyTemplate1IfE
typeinfo name for MyTemplate1<float>
$ c++filt _ZTS11MyTemplate1IiE
typeinfo name for MyTemplate1<int>
```

These `typeinfo` objects are there because, as @Peter commented, the C++ standard
requires that [`typeid` refers to an object of static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

> What exactly is happening under the hood?

You may wonder: Why does the compiler make these `typeinfo` object symbols *weak* rather than simply global?
Why does it define them in different sections of the object file? (sections 10 and 15 of my object file,
sections 2894 and 2899 of yours).

And if we check what *else* is in these sections:

```
$ readelf -s main.o | egrep '(10 |15 )'
     5: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   15 _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
     6: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   10 _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
```

we see that each object is *the only thing* in its section. Why so?

In my `main.o`, those sections 10 and 15 are:

```
$ readelf -t main.o | egrep '(\[10\]|\[15\])'
  [10] .rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
  [15] .rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
```

Each of those is a read-only *data-section* in the sense of:

```
__attribute__((section(.rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE)))
__attribute__((section(.rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE)))
```

that contains *nothing but* the definition of the object after which it is
named.

The compiler gives each of the objects a data-section to all to itself for
the same reason that it makes the symbols `WEAK`.
References to `typeid(MyTemplate1<X>)`, for an arbitrary type `X`, might be made in
multiple translation units within the same linkage that `#include` the definition of
`MyTemplate1`. To head off linkage failure in such cases with *multiple definition* error,
the compiler makes the symbols weak.
The linker will tolerate multiple definitions of a *weak* symbol, resolving
all references simply to the first definition that presents itself and ignoring
the rest. By dedicating a unique data-section (or function-section, as appropriate) to
the definition of each weak template-instantiating symbol the compiler gives the linker freedom to
*discard* any surplus data-or-function sections that define the same weak symbol without
risk of collateral damage to the program. See:

```
$ cat MyTemplate1.hpp
#pragma once

template<class T>
class MyTemplate1
{
public:
    T a;

    MyTemplate1(T other){
        a = other;
    }
};

$ cat foo.cpp
#include "MyTemplate1.hpp"
#include <typeinfo>

int foo()
{
    return typeid(MyTemplate1<int>) == typeid(MyTemplate1<float>);
}

$ cat bar.cpp
#include "MyTemplate1.hpp"
#include <typeinfo>

int bar()
{
    return typeid(MyTemplate1<int>) != typeid(MyTemplate1<float>);
}

$ cat prog.cpp
extern int foo();
extern int bar();

int main()
{
    return foo() && bar();
}
```

If we compile:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -c prog.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

and link (with some diagnostics) like this:

```
$ clang++ -o prog prog.o bar.o foo.o \
         -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE \
         -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE \
         -Wl,-Map=mapfile
/usr/bin/ld: bar.o: definition of _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
/usr/bin/ld: bar.o: definition of _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: reference to _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: reference to _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
```

inputting `bar.o` before `foo.o`, then the linker chooses the definitions of
`_ZTI11MyTemplate1I(f|i)E` from `bar.o` and disregards the definitions in `foo.o`,
resolving the *references* in `foo.o` to the definitions in `bar.o`. And the mapfile shows:

**mapfile (1)**

```
...
Discarded input sections
...
 .rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
                0x0000000000000000       0x10 foo.o
...
 .rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
                0x0000000000000000       0x10 foo.o
...
```

that the definitions in `foo.o` were thrown away. If we relink with the
order of `bar.o` and `foo.o` reversed:

```
$ clang++ -o prog prog.o foo.o bar.o \
             -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE \
             -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE \
             -Wl,-Map=mapfile
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: definition of _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: definition of _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
/usr/bin/ld: bar.o: reference to _ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
/usr/bin/ld: bar.o: reference to _ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
```

then we get the opposite results. The definitions from `foo.o` are linked
and:

**mapfile (2)**

```
...
Discarded input sections
...
 .rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IiE
                0x0000000000000000       0x10 bar.o
...
 .rodata._ZTI11MyTemplate1IfE
                0x0000000000000000       0x10 bar.o
...
```

the ones in `bar.o` are thrown away. This first-come-first-served
principle of the linker is fine because - and *only* because - the definition of `template<class T> MyTemplate1` that the compiler found
in the translation unit `foo.cpp` was *identical* to the one it found in `bar.cpp`, a
condition that the C++ Standard *requires*, in [the One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition),
but which the C++ compiler can do nothing to *enforce*.

You can make essentially the same observations about template-instantiating symbols in general, and what you see with clang++ is essentially the same as what you'll see with g++.